# Laravel 5 HMVC routes issue

Tags: laravel

```
  ->app
     ->assets
     -> Commands 
     -> Console
     -> Events
     -> Exceptions
     -> Handlers
     -> Helpers
     -> Http
     -> Libraries
     -> Models
     -> Modules
     -> Providers
     -> Services
```

please look at the folder structure of my application. You can see Modules are in App folder. Now see Modules folder structure.
    ->Modules
     ->abc
     ->def
     ->ghi
     ->jkl

when i hit url **`localhost/abc/123/xyz`** normally it should go to http        folder and search for 123 controller and function xyz(), but it goes to Modules folder and look for module 123 and controller xyz.

```
    There is no .htaccess file and i don't know why this is happening to me.
    why this is happening and what is could the reason behind this?
```

this is an HMVC not a conventional laravel app but this thing is driving me crazy. Please help me out if you have already expirence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The localhost is not mapped to the folder structure in laravel. its mapped to the public/ folder. the index.php inside the public folder is booting the l5 lifecycle.

The Routing is defined in the routes.php. The Controller can be everywhere but you have to satisfy the psr-namespacing for autoloading.